# C++ Template Function Can't Convert 'std:string' to 'double' in return

Tags: c++, types, compilation

I have a function to get data from environment variables. It works fine when I mention the numerical types, but when I mention the value should be in the string type, then it errors at compile time:

```
g.cc: In instantiation of ‘T result(const char *, const T&) [with T = double; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’:
g.cc:65:88:   required from here
g.cc:23:33: error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’} to ‘double’ in return
   23 |       return std::string(env_val);
      |
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
T result(const char *key, const T &default_value) {
    char *env_val = getenv(key);
    if (std::is_integral<T>::value)
        return atoi(env_val);
    else if(std::is_floating_point<T>::value)
        return atof(env_val);
    else if(std::is_base_of<std::string<char>, T>::value)
        return std::string(env_val);
    return default_value;
}

int main() {
    result<int>("test1", 12);          // Ok
    result<double>("test2", 12.2);       // Ok
    result<std::string>("test3", "test3");  // ERROR
}
```

I've mentioned returning `T` as a result, but it shows this error.

Comment: You want to use `if constexpr …`

Comment: Something is cheese here ... your main calls result with one argument but it seems to have two parameters.

Comment: Second argument doesn't have default value so usage example is invalid.

Comment: @ChrisMM Thank you so much! It works!

Comment: @ÖöTiib Oh sorry, I've updated the question.

Comment: @MarekR Oh sorry, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `constexpr` for your if statements, otherwise the compiler will try to compile each possible route.

```
T result(const char *key, const T &default_value ) {
    char *env_val = getenv(key);
    if constexpr (std::is_integral<T>::value)
        return atoi(env_val);
    else if constexpr (std::is_floating_point<T>::value)
        return atof(env_val);
    else if constexpr (std::is_base_of<std::string, T>::value)
        return std::string(env_val);
    return default_value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if statements here

```cpp
    if (std::is_integral<T>::value)
        return atoi(env_val);
    else if(std::is_floating_point<T>::value)
        return atof(env_val);
    else if(std::is_base_of<std::string<char>, T>::value)
        return std::string(env_val);
```

are not magically going away just because their condition is false. When this template is instantiated with `T = double`, you essentially tell your compiler to compile the following code:

```cpp
double result(const char *key, const double &default_value) {
    char *env_val = getenv(key);
    if (std::is_integral<double>::value)
        return atoi(env_val);
    else if(std::is_floating_point<double>::value)
        return atof(env_val);
    else if(std::is_base_of<std::string, double>::value)
        return std::string(env_val);
    return default_value;
}
```

Note how all the return statements are still there…

Starting with C++17, you can use [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) to actually make the code you don't want go away:

```cpp
template <typename T>
T result(const char *key, const T &default_value) {
    char *env_val = getenv(key);
    if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<T>)
        return atoi(env_val);
    else if constexpr (std::is_floating_point_v<T>)
        return atof(env_val);
    else if constexpr (std::is_base_of_v<std::string, T>)
        return std::string(env_val);
    return default_value;
}
```

Alternatively, you could also use [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae), for example:

```cpp
template <typename T>
auto result(const char* key, const T& default_value) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, T> {
    return std::atoi(getenv(key));
}

template <typename T>
auto result(const char* key, const T& default_value) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, T> {
    return std::atof(getenv(key));
}

template <typename T>
auto result(const char* key, const T& default_value) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<std::string, T>, T> {
    return {getenv(key)};
}
```

Apart from all that, I would suggest to reconsider whether you really want that last version that gives special behavior for classes that are derived from string. This seems to me like a very brittle hack to achieve something that should most-likely have been done in a fundamentally different way. Most notably, it won't work for `T = std::string`…

Answer (score 1):

This is because every branch in the function are compiled unconditionally. Even though these is constants in the `if`s, the compiler has to compile all the branches. Each branch has a different return type, hence the error.

You want to use `if constexpr` instead, which tells the compiler to treat each branch as a separated template that should only be instantiated if the condition is true.

```
template <typename T>
T result(const char *key, const T &default_value) {
    char *env_val = getenv(key);
    if constexpr(std::is_integral<T>::value)
        return atoi(env_val);
    else if constexpr(std::is_floating_point<T>::value)
        return atof(env_val);
    else if constexpr(std::is_base_of<std::basic_string<char>, T>::value)
        return std::string(env_val);
    return default_value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would approach the issue in completely different way:

```cpp
template<typename T>
bool convert_to(std::string_view s, T& result)
{
    std::istringstream input;
    input.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(const_cast<char *>(s.data()), s.length());
    return input >> result >> std::ws && input.eof();
}

bool convert_to(std::string_view s, std::string& result)
{
    result = s;
    return true;
}

template<typename T>
std::optional<T> get_env(std::string_view name)
{
    auto r = getenv(name.data());
    if (!r) return {};
    T result;
    if (!convert_to(r, result)) return {};
    return result;
}

template<typename T>
T get_env_or(std::string_view name, T&& defValue)
{
    return get_env<T>(name).value_or(std::forward<T>(defValue));
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PnAvD0p2vfLyho1o)

Advantage: if you strip `string_view` and `optional` (in this case it is sugar coating) it will work with almost any C++ version.